# Update DataGridView while running test

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am currently writing a piece of functional test (FCT) software used for testing PCBAs. The main interface between the user has a DataGridView that will be used to display all information pertaining to the functional test. I'm also transitioning from LABView to C# to develop these so I'm still learning a bit.

What I want to do at the start of the application is to show a 5 column x 100 row table for the data. I chose 100 rows to make the table fill up the window (it also looks a little better this way too).

The issue I'm having is when I try to add data to the same row. Note that the first set of data put in the grid will only be in two columns, while data added later on will span all five columns. Here's what I'm trying now to update the datagrid:

```
mydatagrid.RowCount = 100; //Put 
int rowIndex; //variable for tracking where I'm placing data on the table 

//Do some stuff that doesn't involve my datagrid

mydatagrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = someData; //This line executes fine 
mydatagrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = someOtherData; //This throws an exception

//Do more stuff that doesn't involve my datagrid
```

Another method to update the table I tried was

```
mydatagrid.Rows.Add(somedata, someotherdata);
```

While this works nicely, it puts the data at the end of the table, rather than at the top.

Also, later on in the app will also need to something like this:

```
activaterelays.clicketyclackety();
makemeasurement();
updatedatagrid(); // This function will put data in all five columns
```

Maybe I am missing something trivial with the setup, at it's my first go at a DataGridView with Windows Forms.

Comment: You are trying to insert data in an inexistent row, you have to create the rows before manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

To use indexing in rows and cells in a DatagridView, you must fill it with data first.

Try something like this:

```
public class MyData {
      public string column1{ get; set;}
      public string column2{ get; set;}
      public string column3{ get; set;}
      public string column4{ get; set;}
      public string column5{ get; set;}
}

var data = new List<MyData>() {...}// You must insert the 100 items

//Loads the data to DatagridView, after this line you will see the DatagridView populated.
mydatagrid.DataSource = data;

//Now you can manipulate it
mydatagrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = someData; 
mydatagrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = otherdata;
```